# Can I save Hints on a file in cloud and use it in Google Cloud Speech API?

Tags: cloud, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech

I would like to use Google Cloud Speech for recognizing speech in a specific domain (healthcare). I know it already allows to add additional words to the vocabulary of the recognizer (word hints), but this must be done with each API call. Do you know if I can save the hints on file in the cloud and then use the URI?